# How to activate clean install of Win 8 upgraded to Win 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, virtualization

I'm creating a VM for website testing that runs Win 8.1.  I started by building a new VM with a clean install of Win 8 Upgrade I purchased.  Then I upgraded that to Win 8.1

Having converted to Mac a few years back, I have lots of Windows licenses that are no longer in use, so upgrading is fully legit.

Since I did not start this process with an existing Win installation the activation process isn't happy.  When I go to activate, my license doesn't work because it's a clean install and, unlike way in the past, it doesn't ask to check my old media.

The questions of the day are:

1. How should I best activate?
2. Will it be easiest to just start over with an XP image?

Comment: There is no such thing as a Clean install upgrade to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8.  Your problem is unlikely because you require a clean install to be frank

Comment: True, but the install of Win 8 was clean off an upgrade CD.

Comment: So?  Just activate your installation.  The license key you have can be activated on either Windows 8.0 or Windows 8.1 it just can't be used to install Windows 8.1

Comment: I tried.  Doesn't accept the key because it was a clean install and doesn't ask for any validation of it being an upgrade.

Comment: You shouldn't even need to activate your installation if your Windows 8 installation was already activated.  If the installation is not activated just Use the phone activation.